# How do I add "ay" to any word got from user's input and the two join as one word

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
my_word=input("enter your word\n").lower()

vowel="aeiou"

pig=my_word+"ay"

if my_word[0] in vowel:

  print('pi')
```

Let's imagine that the user's input is "almighty"
So my Final Results was "almighty ay "
Infact what I need is the final results to be "Almightyay"
So how do I.ake it happen

Comment: Your question title doesn't seem to be aligned with what your code is trying to do. To answer your question... strings can be combined using the + operator. It's as simple as that. Why you're checking the first character against a string of vowels is a mystery

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume your code is supposed to work for more than just one word. Here's a program that converts the input to Pig Latin. It's best understood by running against various input and inspecting the value of `parts` in the `translate_word` function.

[Link to re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)

```
import re


def translate(text: str) -> str:
    return ' '.join([translate_word(w) for w in text.split()])


VOWELS = 'a|e|i|o|u'
CONSONANTS = f'[^{VOWELS}]'


def translate_word(word: str) -> str:
    parts = re.split(rf'({VOWELS}|{CONSONANTS}*qu|xr|y)', word)
    parts = [w for w in parts if w]
    if not (
            re.match(rf'^{VOWELS}|xr', parts[0]) or
            (parts[0] == 'y' and re.match(rf'^{CONSONANTS}', parts[1]))
    ):
        fst = parts.pop(0)
        parts.append(fst)

    parts.append('ay')

    return ''.join(parts)
```

Comment: "Import re" stands for what please dear ...would you explain a little about it please?

Comment: @AlimaWeka May I suggest https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're such a genius..... wish you the best,progress and prosperity in your work ....your help means a lot

Answer (score -1):

Just print the pig string where you did the concatenation in the print statement.

```
my_word=input("enter your word\n").lower()

vowel="aeiou"

pig=my_word+"ay"

if my_word[0] in vowel:

  print('pi')
  print(pig)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code will already achieve what you are looking for. String concatenation in python does not add spaces between strings. If you give the input 'almighty' and print the output variable pig, it will print almightyay.

```
my_word=input("enter your word\n").lower()

vowel="aeiou"

pig=my_word+"ay"

print(pig)
```

See more examples of python string concatenation here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_concatenation.asp